# How can I use Monero RPC via Python

Tags: blockchain, rpc, python

As documented in 
https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html
and
https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html,
Monero can be used programmatically using daemon and wallet RPC.

If I wanted to use Python to extract data from the blockchain, for example nonce values over a block range to run statistics on, what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Monero team recently added a tool that makes it easy to integrate Monero RPC with Python. It can connect to running daemon and wallet and exposes their RPC interfaces:

The following command will connect to a monerod running on mainnet on default settings:

```
utils/python-rpc/console 18081
```

You'll get this output:

```
Variable 'daemon' connected to daemon RPC on 127.0.0.1:18081
>>>
```

You're now in a python interpreter, and the `daemon` variable is set to an object which can call daemon RPC directly, eg:

```
>>> daemon.get_version()
{u'status': u'OK', u'untrusted': False, u'version': 131078}
>>>
```

For the use case above (retrieving 21 nonce values from the blockchain from height 1000):

```
>>> [x.nonce for x in daemon.getblockheadersrange(1000, 1020).headers]
[3419004817, 3320605335, 295465941, 3696734864, 2221411748, 2201153093, 148086550, 524920481, 1766174771, 1831485859, 2409397405, 804573540, 535538542, 1487558207, 3340140970, 4029873826, 3890252333, 586366003, 1681558754, 1323530723, 240084243]
>>>
```

You can also connect the console to several processes, daemon and wallet, so you can interact with both from the same interpreter. The console will detect whether it's connecting to a node or a wallet, and will create the RPC proxy objects as `daemon` or `wallet` accordingly. If you connect to more than one demon or more than one wallet, the RPC objects will be `daemons` and/or `wallets` arrays instead of single variables. For instance, if you have a wallet running on port 8080:

```
$ utils/python-rpc/console 18081 8080
Variable 'daemon' connected to daemon RPC on 127.0.0.1:18081
Variable 'wallet' connected to wallet RPC on 127.0.0.1:8080
>>>
```

The console tool accepts full URLs if the daemon/wallet does not run on 127.0.0.1.

To use that framework in other Python programs, you should import the module(s) you need:

```
from framework.daemon import Daemon
from framework.wallet import Wallet
```

Comment: The answer shows using the new console tool, but doesn't show how to mix with other python code. Perhaps also reference: https://moneroexamples.github.io/python-json-rpc/ which shows calling the RPC interfaces directly from standalone python scripts.

Comment: You can add that as a new answer.

Comment: Reading that link you posted, I actually thought this was a separate Python library, as I know of a few that exist (and not having used them before). Anyway, I added the import statements at the end for completeness as you suggested.

Comment: Yeah there are a few libraries floating around. None are really what I would call complete though. Even this new utility doesn't implement every method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user36303's answer, it's worth also noting you can call the RPC interfaces directly from Python of course. Example code: https://moneroexamples.github.io/python-json-rpc/

This is essentially what the new Python utility referenced does under-the-hood.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to take the command you want from the RPC documentation:

`$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block_header_by_height","params":{"height":912345}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Paste it into https://curl.trillworks.com:

Copy the output:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block_header_by_height","params":{"height":912345}}'

response = requests.post('http://curl', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Note, if you want to do something more than just data crunching, I highly recommend the super simple [Monero-python](https://monero-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.